# PyCharm can not resolve PyGObject 3.0, but code runs fine

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, pycharm, pygobject

I'm using PyCharm 2.5 on Ubuntu 11.10, trying to develop an application using PyGObject 3.0 on Python 3.2.2. I've installed the Ubuntu package python3-gobject, and when I run my code, it works exactly as expected.

However, PyCharm can not seem to find any of the PyGObject modules. It says `Unresolved refrence: 'Gtk'` when I hover over Gtk in my import statement, and of course none of the auto-completion works.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I've even tried making a python virtual environment and then installing PyGObject from source into it, and then even tried making symlinks from all the .py files in `site-packages/gi/overrides` to `site-packages/gi/repository`, all with no luck.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Gtk+ 3 Python bindings to binary modules are generated dynamically using `*.typelib` databases. The dynamic importer for accessing all the modules is located in `gi.repository`. PyCharm cannot detect these modules using its code insight, because they require special handling.

I've filed a feature request for this issue: [PY-6932](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6932). Feel free to vote for it.

Comment: Ah, PyGObject is very fancy indeed. Voted for your feature, maybe we can have it some day! :D

Comment: Also, would any other IDE support this? I'm about to develop a moderate-sized GTK+ 3 application and would love to have a good IDE to use for it. What would this feature be called so that I can search for it?

Comment: You could use bpython or bpython3

Comment: The issue is fixed. From the support, it says: "hit `Alt + Enter` on 
`from gi.repository import Gt<caret>k` and choose "Generate stubs for binary module" " and it worked!

Comment: Please update your answer with solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33646560/57952

Answer (score 61):

Position the text cursor inside the redlined `Gtk` in:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose "Generate stubs for binary module"