# Python Gtk+ development in Linux using Eclipse + PyDev, Unresolved import: Gtk

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, gtk, pydev

I just tried to write my first Gtk+ program using python in linux mint with Eclipse + PyDev, but I met this error in PyDev, Unresolved import: Gtk

program source code: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

error shown as below:

[image]

Program can run. I checked PYTHONPATH in PyDev, I think it's right. 
[image]

How can I fix this problem?

By the way, could you give some advice about nice free IDE for Python & Gtk+ development in Linux?

Comment: Does it work from the regular Python console?

Comment: @jadkik94 Yes, it can run in terminal by python command too.

Comment: From the command line, after importing `Gtk` see what `Gtk.__path__` is and if it's in Pydev's PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @jadkik94 Gtk.__path__ is /usr/lib/girepository-1.0/Gtk-3.0.typelib I have alread add /usr/lib/girepository-1.0 into PYTHONPATH, but not fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Window->Preferences** and add "gi" to "Forced Builtins" (see screenshots).
You should try [**Glade for GTK3**](https://glade.gnome.org/) gui design (see screenshot).
See final result screenshot.
You could also use [**Sublime Text 3**](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, as it actually solves the issue and add code completion.

Answer (score 1):

same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418828/1040891

> In Gtk+ 3 Python bindings to binary modules are generated dynamically
>   using *.typelib databases. The dynamic importer for accessing all the
>   modules is located in gi.repository. PyCharm cannot detect these
>   modules using its code insight, because they require special handling.

Note: [IPython](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html) can detect and handle these modules

Comment: Problem is explained, but not solved: what "special handling" the `gi.repository` modules need to remove the false error mark and enable so autompletion?

Answer (score 1):

You must use Python 3.x.

Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->PyDev->Python Interpreter*->Advanced Auto-Config->/usr/share/python3.3**->Ok->Apply->Ok

*If using Python, instead of Jython or IronPython

**If Python 3.3 installed, otherwise try python3, but I've not tested.