# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module

Tags: python, linux, gtk

I installed gtk+ on my Ubuntu 13.10 successfully(apparently!) using jhbuild following this link:
http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

but when i run the following simple program:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

i get this error:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "intro.py", line 4, in <module>
    win=GtkWindow()
NameError: name 'GtkWindow' is not defined
```

On searching around a bit , i found these similar questions:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed
https://askubuntu.com/questions/208431/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module?rq=1

but i still get the error.

and these:

[Python Gtk+ development in Linux using Eclipse + PyDev, Unresolved import: Gtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878665/python-gtk-development-in-linux-using-eclipse-pydev-unresolved-import-gtk)
[PyCharm can not resolve PyGObject 3.0, but code runs fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417921/pycharm-can-not-resolve-pygobject-3-0-but-code-runs-fine/11418828#11418828)

don't really give a solution.

How can i fix this?

UPDATE 1: So, apparently the error was due to GtkWindow instead of Gtk.Window in the code, but even after correcting it , the same warnings are displayed (although, now i don't get the error and get the correct output)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" Unable to connect to dbus - Sublime text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058926/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-unable-to-connect-to-db)

Answer (score 1):

According to your traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "intro.py", line 4, in <module>
    win=GtkWindow()
NameError: name 'GtkWindow' is not defined
```

In your code sample on line 4 you have:

```
win = Gtk.Window()
```

But the error is indicating you actually have:

```
win=GtkWindow()
```

You accidentally omitted the `.` between `Gtk` and `Window` in your actual code but fixed it in the example you posted. I'd suggest double checking that line in *intro.py* to see if this fixes your problem.

- NOTE: This is entirely unrelated to the warnings about failing to load those 3 modules.

Comment: @curiousguy13 Is your system 32 or 64bit?

Comment: my os is 64 bit(it is a virtual system running on vmware , although that shouldn't matter) but i have tried installing the overlay scrollbar and other modules in 32 bit and 64 bit versions both

Answer (score 0):

To me the right answer was to specify the GTK module position: simply write in the terminal

```
export GTK_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0
```

and a similar reasoning for the other modules.

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling the package, it may have been an error when installation happened.