# STILL: PyCharm can not resolve PyGObject 3.0, but code runs fine

Tags: python, pycharm, gtk3, pygobject

This question has been asked before [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417921/pycharm-can-not-resolve-pygobject-3-0-but-code-runs-fine). At the time, it was a bug, and a feature has been requested, later on it was fixed and supposedly it should work.

but in my case it still isn't.
I have been trying and googling for about a week, yet still, I couldn't get it to work

My system is:

- Arch Linux
- Pycharm 3.1.1 Build #PC-133.881
- Python 3.3.4
- pygobject 3.10.2

Is there something I'm missing or is it a bug ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than repeating a question we prefer that you edit or comment on the old question, that bumps it back up to the top of various lists. You might want to specify in your question what exactly doesn't work and what you tried and googled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyCharm can not resolve PyGObject 3.0, but code runs fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417921/pycharm-can-not-resolve-pygobject-3-0-but-code-runs-fine)

Comment: you my friend have not even read my question. I already mentioned the original question. and I'm saying it STILL Doesn't work !. please don't comment just for the sake of it.

Comment: I'm not commenting just for the sake of it. I did read your question and it's the same as the original question. We don't allow duplicate questions here, even if the original one hasn't gotten a good answer. Please edit or comment on the old question, or at least specify what exactly doesn't work and what you tried and googled. There is no need to be rude.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude, sorry about that. I have looked a lot on google about this issue. apart from the previous question, there is no mention of the problem at all. I've just started using PyCharm, and I want to write some GTK+3 apps with it. The problem is when I do: from gi.repository import Gtk. Gtk is not a recognized reference. however when I run the code it works perfectly. The previous question shows what the problem is. and the solution was a feature request. the report of the bug says it's fixed and I have a version that supposedly should work. but it doesn't at all.

Comment: Sounds like you should post at the PyCharm bug report. I expect it's something to do with your PyCharm configuration. I don't know enough about PyCharm to give you an answer. Or if you add a comment to the answer on the old question, one of those people might be able to help you configure it so that it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a new bug in PyCharm. Forcing skeleton generation should resolve the problem until you run the program, but at least in my case is not working.

Follow [PY-13505](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13505) for more info.

Comment: This should really be a comment as it does not answer the original question.

Comment: The question was: Is there something I'm missing or **is it a bug** ?? I suppose it could have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

The generation of the Gtk.py stub by PyCharm fails because of default IDE file size limit. I changed the config value "idea.max.intellisense.filesize" in idea.properties from 2500 to 10000. The stub generation takes some time but finishes now.

I think this might solve your issue developing Gtk3 applications with PyCharm to get features like autocompletion and integrated API-documentation.

This was also my answer to a very similar question: [PyCharm - autocomplete for Gtk3 magically stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254065/pycharm-autocomplete-for-gtk3-magically-stops-working)

Comment: Please don't use a link as an answer. It's allowed to take the solution out of the link and keep the link as well. Links can and do rot, and this might not work when the next user has this problem.