# PyCharm - autocomplete for Gtk3 magically stops working

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm, gtk3

I have this weird problem - I'm learning Gtk3 on Windows 7 with PyCharm Community 3.4.1. When I try to import Gtk:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

it underlines Gtk as unresolved reference, becouse it's a binary module. Then I press Alt+Enter and choose "Generate methon stubs for binary module..." and wait until it it finishes indexing. Then I happily write this simple empty window with autocomplete working correctly:

```
class Okienko(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title='Okienko')

app = Okienko()
app.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
app.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I run it, it shows me a nice empty Gtk window. So far so good.

**BUT.**

Bad things happen - autocomplete for Gtk module simply vanishes! `from gi.repository import Gtk` gets underlined red and autocomplete gives me just names which I've previously used (`Window` and `main` in this case). The only thing I can do is to Invalidate cache and restart Pycharm and go over this procedure again... I also tried .NET classes in IronPython - it's even worse, indexing takes several minutes and doesn't even finish.

Answer (score 11):

In PyCharm community edition 3.4.1 (mint 17), to make Gtk3 autocompletion works:

1. In file: "pycharm.community-3.4.1/bin/idea.properties" comment the
   line:  "idea.max.intellisense.filesize=2500"
2. Restart the IDE
3. In your code: from gi.repository import Gtk strike Alt-Enter and select
   "Generate stubs for binary module"

Comment: This is the same for the Professional edition, can confirm that this works. For Ubuntu it's /opt/pycharm/bin/idea.properties

Comment: JetBrains products now have a _Help > Edit Custom Properties..._ menu item that gives you easy access to a file meant for user overrides of the idea.properties. The same solution works, but now it's a matter of adding an entry to increase the default limit: `idea.max.intellisense.filesize=10000`.

Comment: The third step does not work for me. Perhaps I already have some stubs generated that are not containing everything. My problem is that the autocompletion works for `box = Gtk.HButtonBox()` but then not for `box.`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and found out that the Gtk.py file is too big for IDE file size limit allowed by PyCharm. I changed the config value "idea.max.intellisense.filesize" in idea.properties from 2500 to 10000. The stub generation takes some time but finishes now.

Hope that helps even Windows users. Feedback appreciated.

Comment: This is the same for the Professional edition, can confirm that this works. For Ubuntu it's /opt/pycharm/bin/idea.properties