# pycharm hint Nautilus, Gtk, GObject, Gio, GLib unresolved

Tags: python

I'm using python2.7 to build a file manager project,
but in pycharm the below code hints these references unresolved.

```
from gi.repository import Nautilus, Gtk, GObject, Gio, GLib
```

I have installed python-gi in ubuntu14.04, cannot search python-gi use pip.
How can I import these modules?

Comment: the hint (cake) is a lie... at least for GLib...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyCharm can not resolve PyGObject 3.0, but code runs fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417921/pycharm-can-not-resolve-pygobject-3-0-but-code-runs-fine)